# Why do I get the error "Service not found" when trying to get my jwt

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, jwt, auth0

When I trying to call jwt to authenticate via auth0, it throws an error: "Service not found: http://localhost:8000".

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect } from 'react'
import Header from '../Header/Header'
import Footer from '../Footer/Footer'
import { Outlet } from "react-router-dom"
import { useAuth0 } from "@auth0/auth0-react"
import UserDetailContext from '../../context/UserDetailContext'
import { useMutation } from "react-query";
import { createUser } from '../../utils/api.js'

const Layout = () => {

    const { isAuthenticated, user, getAccessTokenWithPopup } = useAuth0()
    const { setUserDetails } = useContext(UserDetailContext)

    const { mutate } = useMutation({
        mutationKey: [user?.email],
        mutationFn: (token) => createUser(user?.email, token)
    });

    useEffect(() => {

        const getTokenAndRegister = async () => {
            const res = await getAccessTokenWithPopup({
                authorizationParams: {
                    audience: "http://localhost:8000",
                    scope: "openid profile email"
                }
            })
            localStorage.setItem("access_token", res)
            setUserDetails((prev) => ({ ...prev, token: res }));
            console.log(res)
        }

        isAuthenticated && getTokenAndRegister()
    }, [isAuthenticated]);
    return (
        <>
            <div style={{ background: "var(--black)", overflow: "hidden" }}>
                <Header />
                <Outlet />
            </div>
            <Footer />
        </>
    )
}

export default Layout
```

## auth0Config.js

```
import {auth} from 'express-oauth2-jwt-bearer'

const  jwtCheck = auth({
    audience: "http://localhost:8000",
    issuerBaseURL: "my url)",
    tokenSigningAlg: "RS256"
})

export default jwtCheck
```

## main.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import { Auth0Provider } from "@auth0/auth0-react"

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Auth0Provider
    domain="my domain)"
    clientId="rmy id)"
    authorizationParams={{
      redirect_uri: "http://localhost:5173"
    }}
    audience="http://localhost:8000"
    scope="openid profile email"
    >
    <App />
    </Auth0Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8CAx.png)

I tried to rewrite the code from scratch but no luck. Also updated all dependencies to the latest versions, the error persists. Instead of a token, I get a service not found.

Comment: Who is listening on port 8000?  Where's your server?

Comment: @TimRoberts this is my own local server